# Boolean Expression Example

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, boolean

> Given variables `model`, `year`, and `make`, write a boolean
>   expression that evaluates to `True` if `make` contains the value
>   `'ford'` and `year` is greater than `2013` or if `model` holds
>   `'mustang'` and `year` is greater than or equal to `2012`, `False`
>   otherwise.

I am confused on how to represent the 'contains' and 'hold' in the expression.

My answer:

```
if make == 'ford' and year > 2013:
    return True
elif model >= 'mustang' and year >= 2012:
  return True
else False
```

Comment: Please complete (or at least *attempt*) your own homework.

Comment: break it down into two parts. First get yourself an expression for the ford 2013 criterion. Then get one that works for mustang. Put each in parentheses, then combine with an "or." [You need to fill in how "and" and "or" are represented in Python]

Comment: So where's your answer? What led you to that answer, and why do you think it might be wrong? SO isn't a tutorial service, if you need support studying talk to the relevant professor/TA.

Comment: [Container Datatypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

Comment: looks like you need model == 'mustang'. Also, the word "contains" here is ambiguous. So like if model is "ford windstar", it is not clear what is the expected behavior. If that does not count as "ford" your code is close. If it is supposed to count, you need to check if "ford" is a substring. Also, you may need to pay attention to what happens if we are passed "Ford" with a capital F.

Comment: also where you have else false, I am wondering if you need return false. But the whole return thing looks a little iffy to me, because it asked for an expression, not a function, so more like: ((make == 'ford') and (year > 2013)) or  ((model == 'mustang') and (year >= 2012)).

Comment: `contains` may means `if "ford" in model` (or `if "ford" in model.lower()`)

Comment: You should ask your professor (or whoever gave you this problem) for clarification on the meaning of ``contain`` and ``hold``

Comment: Thank you!! @JeremyKahan

Comment: Thank you @furas !!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a few simple errors, I think this is what you want. "Contains" and "holds", I believe, just refer to variables.

```
make = "ford"
model = "mustang"
year = 2012

def cars(make, model, year):
    if make == 'ford' and year > 2013:
        return True
    elif model == 'mustang' and year >= 2012:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you so much!